# BinarySecurityToken in log

Tags: .net, wcf, security

I am trying to get the `BinarySecurityToken` logged in order to see the ID and digest of it. I followed the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730318%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) but still the output is

```
<o:BinarySecurityToken>
<!-- Removed-->
</o:BinarySecurityToken>
```

Using `.NET 3.5` how can I get this logged? I don't want to use a sniffer like Wireshark.

Comment: You might want to post this as an answer instead of a comment so that the question can get closed - the question and answer is interesting enough that it should be kept for posterity, IMO.

Comment: Good remark, thanks (I'm new here). Done

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that logKnownPii="true" needs to be added to the first source in app.config, and this source must be named System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging. Works now.

Comment: Needs to be added to machine config as well:
<configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
      <machineSettings enableLoggingKnownPii="true"/>
   </system.serviceModel>
</configuration> 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730318(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to set `logKnownPii` to `true` under `system.serviceModel/diagnostics/messageLogging` in app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logKnownPii="true" logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000"/>
</diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" logKnownPii="true">
    <listeners>
      <add initializeData="C:\trace.log" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="messages"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

As well as under `configuration/system.serviceModel/machineSettings` in machine.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <machineSettings enableLoggingKnownPii="true"/>
```